# How to resolve Cross Origin Error In React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, cross-domain

I have made a simple shopping cart using React.js. I am using localStorage to store the state value so that even after the refresh, the values remain in the UI.

> Also, does modifying the Items content through states, change the
> original Items content?

Following are the different files that I am using to render:

**ShoppingCart.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Table, Button, Media, Card, CardHeader, CardBody, CardFooter } from 'reactstrap';
import Items from '../shared/Items';

class ShoppingCart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            items: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items")) || Items
        }
    }

    decreaseQuantity = (item) => {
        const copy = this.state.items;
        item.quantity -= 1;

        for(let i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
            if(copy[i].id === item.id)
                copy[i] = item;
        }

        localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(copy));

        this.setState({
            items: copy
        });
    };

    increaseQuantity = (item) => {
        const copy = this.state.items;
        item.quantity += 1;

        for(let i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
            if(copy[i].id === item.id)
                copy[i] = item;
        }

        localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(copy));

        this.setState({
            items: copy
        });
    };

    resetCart = () => {
        localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(Items));

        this.setState({
            items: Items
        })
    };

    removeItem = (item) => {
        let copy = this.state.items;

        copy.splice(copy.indexOf(item), 1);

        localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(copy));

        this.setState({
            items: copy
        });
    }

    render() {
        const array = this.state.items;

        const total = array.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.quantity, 0);
        let typeDiscount = 0;
        let normalDiscount = 0;
        const totalPrice = array.reduce((acc, item) => {
            normalDiscount += ((item.quantity * item.price) * item.discount) / 100;

            if (item.type === "fiction")
                typeDiscount += ((item.quantity * item.price) * 15) / 100;
            
            return acc + (item.quantity * item.price);
        }, 0);

        const items = array.map((item) => (
            <tr key={item.id}>
                <td>
                    <Media>
                        <Media left className="mr-3">
                            <Media object data-src={item.img_url} style={{height: 20, width: 20}} placeholder={item.name} />
                        </Media>
                        <Media body>
                            {item.name}
                            <Button close onClick={() => this.removeItem(item)} />
                        </Media>
                    </Media>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <Button color="danger" className="mr-3" disabled={item.quantity === 1} 
                    onClick={() => this.decreaseQuantity(item)}>
                        -
                    </Button>
                    {item.quantity}
                    <Button color="success" className="ml-3" onClick={() => this.increaseQuantity(item)}>+</Button>
                </td>
                <td>{item.quantity * item.price}</td>
            </tr>
        ));

        

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md">
                        <Table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Item({total})</th>
                                    <th>Qty</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {items}
                            </tbody>
                        </Table>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md">
                            <Card>
                                <CardHeader>Total</CardHeader>
                                <CardBody>
                                    <dl className="row p-1">
                                        <dt className="col-6">Items({total})</dt>
                                        <dd className="col-6">{totalPrice}</dd>
                                        <br />
                                        <dt className="col-6">Discount</dt>
                                        <dd className="col-6">{normalDiscount}</dd>
                                        <dt className="col-6">Type Discount</dt>
                                        <dd className="col-6">{typeDiscount}</dd>
                                    </dl>
                                </CardBody>
                                <CardFooter>
                                    <dl className="row p-1">
                                        <dt className="col-6">Order Total</dt>
                                        <dd className="col-6">{totalPrice - normalDiscount - typeDiscount}</dd>
                                    </dl>
                                </CardFooter>
                            </Card>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br /><br />
                <Button style={{position: "absolute", right: 500}} color="primary" className="mt-5" onClick={this.resetCart}>Reset</Button>                
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default ShoppingCart;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ShoppingCart from './components/ShoppingCart';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="mt-5">
      <ShoppingCart />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**Items.js**

```
//The JSON file containing the items data
const Items = [{ "id": 9090, "name": "Item1", "price": 200, "discount": 10, "type": "fiction", "img_url": "https://place-hold.it/40.jpg", "quantity": 1 }, 
    { "id": 9091, "name": "Item2", "price": 250, "discount": 15, "type": "literature", "img_url": "https://place-hold.it/40.jpg", "quantity": 1 }, 
    { "id": 9092, "name": "Item3", "price": 320, "discount": 5, "type": "literature", "img_url": "https://place-hold.it/40.jpg", "quantity": 1 }, 
    { "id": 9093, "name": "Item4", "price": 290, "discount": 0, "type": "thriller", "img_url": "https://place-hold.it/40.jpg", "quantity": 1 }, 
    { "id": 9094, "name": "Item5", "price": 500, "discount": 25, "type": "thriller", "img_url": "https://place-hold.it/40.jpg", "quantity": 1 }, 
    { "id": 9095, "name": "Item6", "price": 150, "discount": 5, "type": "literature", "img_url": "https://place-hold.it/40.jpg", "quantity": 1 }, 
    { "id": 9096, "name": "Item7", "price": 700, "discount": 22, "type": "literature", "img_url": "https://place-hold.it/40.jpg", "quantity": 1 }, 
    { "id": 9097, "name": "Item8", "price": 350, "discount": 18, "type": "fiction", "img_url": "https://place-hold.it/40.jpg", "quantity": 1 }];

export default Items;
```

I tried running the app, but I kept on getting the following error:

```
Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.
```

Can someone help me with this? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I hope this helps [https://reactjs.org/docs/cross-origin-errors.html](https://reactjs.org/docs/cross-origin-errors.html)

Comment: I tried it, but nothing that served me well.